# Canjs model returns undefined after resolved

Tags: javascriptmvc, canjs, canjs-model

I cannot find a way to retrieve data from the server and convert them to model instance. I folloed the instructions [here](http://donejs.com/docs.html#!can.Model.static.model) but it's still doesn't work.
Here is my setup:

url for the service: `services/foo/barOne`. The response is : `{"calendar":1352793756534,"objectId":"id2"}`

The model is defined as follow:

```
var myModel = can.Model(
  model: function(raw) {
    newObject = {id:raw.objectId};
    return can.Model.model.call(this,newObject);
  },

  findOne: {
    url: 'services/foo/barOne',
    datatype: 'json'
  }

)
```

And here is how I use that:

```
myBar = myModel.findOne()
myBar.then(function() {
  console.log("resolved with arguments:",arguments); //[undefined]
})
```

I put various log and tracked all of function called, the request is correctly done, and the ajax resolved correctly. The `model` method is also correct and return an object of type `Constructor` with the right parameters.
But after that, inside the `pipe` function of canjs, the result is lost (ie, I got the result `undefined` when `d.resolve.apply(d, arguments)` is called)

What is wrong with this scenario ?
I am using canJS with jquery version 1.0.7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you need a custom converter just for changing the id. You can change it by setting the static `id` property. Try it like this:

```
var MyModel = can.Model({
  id : 'objectId'
}, {
  findOne: 'services/foo/barOne'
});

MyModel.findOne({ id : 'test' }).done(function(model) {
  console.log(model);
});
```

Comment: Your example 'should' work. If I only want to do name translation it's fine, but I want to do some processing before wrapping the data in the model.
And also there is a problem in can.jquery.js (cf my post on the canJS [forum](https://forum.javascriptmvc.com/#Topic/32525000001079183)

Comment: Mark as solved. My version of can.js wasn't up to date. USing the latest one fixed the problem. Full thread [here](https://forum.javascriptmvc.com/topic/custom-model-method#32525000001081163)